# fm_transmitter is not working with other wav sound

Tags: pi-2, ffmpeg

I have working fm_transmitter with this https:// github.com/SandPox/fm_transmitter on raspberry pi 2 but it is working with only "star_wars.wav" file. I have checked star_wars.wav file codec information in VLC media player.

[image: properties]

I have converted some Mp3 to same wav(pcm singed 16-bit little endian mono) format with FFmpeg with below command.(Not working with fm_transmitter)

```
ffmpeg -i fm.mp3 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -acodec pcm_s16le  output.wav
```

Also tried online converter http:// audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav to convert into wav file(pcm_s16le)

Both ffmeg and online converter is not working.
[image: fm]

Original wav file: https:// github.com/SandPox/fm_transmitter/blob/master/star_wars.wav (working)

**My question:**

What am i missing here? does anybody played other wav file song?

**Found working FM:**

https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds (works with pi2 and all wav files also with mp3)